# no exception in camel route when active mq disk space is full

Tags: apache-camel

I've camel route which is reading from file and pushing the content to active mq queue. In case if the broker disk space is full (may be by some other process which is causing disk space issue), camel route stops pushing content to queue, but no exception is being thrown. I need to raise an alert and send email using on exception block in this case.

Comment: show us your route. You can add a Exception block(`doTry` and `doCatch`) in your route. are you sure you dont get any exception

Answer (score 0):

You can try to configure the jms/activemq connection factory to use sync sending (turn off async send) so if the broker does not accept the message due disk full etc, then the client (eg Camel) would be able to detect this and raise an exception.

See details at:

- http://activemq.apache.org/async-sends.html
- http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-enable-asynchronous-sending.html

Comment: thanks claus for quick input, but when tried to enabled async=false, still no exception being thrown by route.

Comment: are you using jms or amqp as protocol? And what versions of Camel and MQ are you using?